# Get the intersect edges length lively

Tags: mesh, interface

I am trying to do body measurements in blender. For example I have a body mesh, and a plane, once the plane intersect the body on bust part, I can take the convex hull of the intersected vertices to get the measurements.

I've tried these add-on interesection(http://airplanes3d.net/scripts-253_e.xml), and measureit, they worked but I have to click them every single time once I move the plane into different body part which I would like to show the measurement lively.

I've seen the blender able to visually draw these intersect path in UI (as the figure shows) whenever I move the plane, but how can I retrieve these informations?

[image: The red circle showed the intersection between a plane and mesh]

Answer (score 1):

My strategy here is to create a curve so that we can measure the length of that curve.

So the first thing to do is to create an intersection.  We are given a manifold (among other things, watertight) mesh and a plane (with four verts).  I'm going to output onto a third object, which I'm displaying in wireframe, which gets the geometry nodes modifier and outputs the measurement.  The first problem is that using a boolean with non-manifold meshes is unreliable, and our plane is definitely non-manifold:

[image]

So I'm going to extrude the plane for purposes of the boolean, and then delete any vertices in the boolean's output that are far from the original plane:

[image]

You'll notice that I can't just use distance is equal to 0 because of precision issues, but I still want the threshold to be very, very small, as the nature of our boolean means that we can have verts very close to our plane that we still don't want.

We now have a mesh without any interior edges, which we could turn into a curve and then measure the length pretty easily, but you want the convex hull of this mesh, and convex hull will make interior edges.  So let's make a sort of extruded convex hull (to avoid precision issues), and then raycast our wire mesh onto this hull:

[image]

Finally, we need to measure the length of this wire.  We'll turn it into a circle, then make some vertices and place them at an X position equal to the length.  We can shrinkwrap an empty to the vertices of this object, and the empty's X position will indicate the measurement:

[image]

If we'd like, we could use the X transform of this empty to drive any visual display we'd like, including a numerical display in geometry nodes, a color indication, a lengthening tape measure mesh, a slowly fattening Suzanne....

[image]

Note that in this particular case, if you run the plane through the middle of the manifold mesh, as you have in your image, the measurement will include the line running through the middle of the mesh.  You haven't specified how exactly you'd like this to be handled.

Note also that any GN measurements like this are in *object space*, so if you want world space measurements, don't scale your GN object.  (There'd be no reason to do so anyways, it doesn't even output its original geometry.)  You can still safely scale the plane or the mesh being measured, and the world space measurements will hold.

Edit: Oh, and one more thing here.  The way that I'm making my convex hull, this won't work with a plane rotated exactly to the vertical.  It would have been smarter of me to translate in the average normal of the input plane, plus or minus.